# Radio button rating system for various categories of questions that add a score at the end

Tags: php, radio-button, addition, vote, rate

I have a php page that has a few HTML questions on it, each question has a "type" and you answer that question on a scale of 1-5, In the example below there would be 3 question types: A, B, & C. How can I add the TOTAL score for each question "type"(score is made from the radio buttons for the 1-5 scale below each question) and then have those total scores stored as PHP variables?

Here is the HTML code, I have NO CLUE where to start but I need to make this for a school event we are doing soon and I don't wanna let them down :) Haha! Thanks for all the help guys, sorry I know so little about HTML forms! Anyways, here's the HTML code, the php can go anywhere I haven't written it yet /: haha:

```
Type A rating:
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
1
<input type="radio" name="select" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="5">
5
</form>
<br><br>
Type B rating:
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
1
<input type="radio" name="select" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="5">
5
</form>
<br><br>
Type A rating:
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
1
<input type="radio" name="select" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="5">
5
</form>
<br><br>
Type C rating:
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
1
<input type="radio" name="select" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="5">
5
</form>
<br><br>
Type A rating:
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
1
<input type="radio" name="select" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="5">
5
</form>
<br><br>
Type B rating:
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
1
<input type="radio" name="select" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="5">
5
</form>
<br><br>
Type B rating:
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
1
<input type="radio" name="select" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="5">
5
</form>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="Sum The Ratings" value="Vote">
```

Comment: To understand why your question was closed, please read the [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a big form with all the questions in it, then for each question, set the name of the input with a keyword different for each questions. When you will treat your form, you will get with $_POST['name'] the value selected, just add them and make a ration or wathever you wan't

```
<?php
$name_cat_a = "A_";
$name_cat_b = "B_";
$cat_a_quest = array("Question A1", "Question A2");
$cat_b_quest = array("Question B1", "Question B2");
if(!isset($_POST[submit])){
echo '<form action="test.php" method=post>';
echo 'Type A rating:';
echo '<br />';
$ind = 0;
foreach($cat_a_quest as $question){
    echo $question;
    echo '<br>';
    $name = $name_cat_a . $ind;
    $ind ++;
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$name.'" value="'.($i+1).'" />'.($i+1) ;
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
echo 'Type B rating:';
echo '<br />';
$ind = 0;
foreach($cat_b_quest as $question){
    echo $question;
    echo '<br>';
    $name = $name_cat_b . $ind;
    $ind ++;
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$name.'" value="'.($i+1).'" />'.($i+1);
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
echo '<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />';
echo '<input type="submit" name="Sum The Ratings" value="Vote">';
echo '</form>';
}
else{
$moyen_a = 0;
$moyen_b = 0;
$nmb_ques_a = count($cat_a_quest);
$nmb_ques_b = count($cat_b_quest);
for($i=0; $i<$nmb_ques_a; $i++){
     $moyen_a = $moyen_a + intval($_POST['A_'.$i]);
}
$moyen_a = $moyen_a / $nmb_ques_a;
for($i=0; $i<$nmb_ques_b; $i++){
     $moyen_b = $moyen_b + intval($_POST['B_'.$i]);
}
$moyen_b = $moyen_b / $nmb_ques_b;


echo 'A:'.$moyen_a.'<br />';
echo 'B:'.$moyen_b.'<br />';
}
?>
```

There i have explicitely name cat_a and cat_b but you can put all your cat in an array, then you loop into it, in this loop, you loop while ther is questions, and then you loop for the 5 answers

Comment: Every time I try that it returns 0 for the value /: Isn't this code also just averaging the scores? I need the sum of all questions with type A and the sum of all questions with type B and so on, there will be multiple type A questions etc.

Comment: Nevermind I entered something wrong, it wasn't just returning zero, your code works but it still isn't what I'm looking for. I could manually name each question and add all the values but the problem is there are about 95 questions in all haha. Worst case scenario it takes me about 30 minutes to do that but I'm wondering if there is a quicker way?

Comment: I just edit the code, but you can take the question from the database it doesn't matter, create loop depending on the number of query

Comment: I just correct all the little syntaxic error, now it's fully working